# Length of chord in circle

Tags: circles

4. In Figure 3, arc CD is a semicircle. AB is perpendicular to CD, BC = 3, BD = 4. Then the length of AB =

a) 3.25   b) 4.56   c) 3.46  d) 7.00
[image: Figure 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

Note that $\angle CAD=90^\circ$, and so $AC^2+AD^2=CD^2$.

Letting $AB=x$, since
$$AC^2=x^2+3^2, AD^2=x^2+4^2, CD^2=7^2$$

you'll get an equation of $x$ as
$$7^2=9+x^2+x^2+16\iff x^2=12.$$

Answer (score 3):

You have a rectangular triangle ACD. Use Euklids sentence (h^2 = p*q = 12 and therefore AB = sqare root of 12 = 3,46...

Comment: I don't know why but it is not appearing. I just made my account here.

Comment: Now I see it, thanks.
This means you have a rectangular triangle ACD. Use Euklids sentence (h^2 = p*q = 12 and therefore AB = sqare root of 12 = 3,46...

Comment: @Bernd: Please edit your Answer now to include that solution.